# Orbeon forms, dropdown items set from selected checkbox values

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

Im working with the FormBuilder: Orbeon Forms 2016.2.1.201609272302 PE.

Ive been trying to create a dynamically populating dropdown list from the checked (selected) values in a checkbox control field (i.e., every checked value is on option in the dropdown)

Heres the example i've been working with,

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude" xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>gtest</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <control-2>t5 t4</control-2>
                    <control-4/>
                    <control-3/>
                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>
        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="control-2-bind" ref="control-2" name="control-2" />
                <xf:bind id="control-3-bind" ref="control-3" name="control-3" />
                <xf:bind id="control-4-bind" ref="control-4" name="control-4" calculate="$control-2" />
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>
        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>test</application-name>
                <form-name>test</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">gtest</title>
                <description xml:lang="en">testing dynamic dropdown based on checklist values.</description>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>
        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size="" />
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size="" />
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>
        <!-- All form resources -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <control-2>
                        <label>checklist</label>
                        <hint/><item><label>t1</label><hint/><value>t1</value>
                        </item><item><label>t2</label><hint/><value>t2</value>
                        </item><item><label>t3</label><hint/><value>t3</value>
                        </item><item><label>t4</label><hint/><value>t4</value>
                        </item><item><label>t5</label><hint/><value>t5</value>
                        </item><item><label>t6</label><hint/><value>t6</value>
                        </item><item><label>t7</label><hint/><value>t7</value>
                        </item>
                    </control-2>
                    <control-4>
                        <label>selected values</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-4>
                    <control-3>
                        <label>dynamic dropdown list</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <xf:itemset ref="$control-2">
                            <xf:label ref="." />
                            <xf:value ref="." />
                        </xf:itemset>
                    </control-3>
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Dropdown from checklist</label>
                    </section-1>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>
        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label" />
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:select id="control-2-control" appearance="full" bind="control-2-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-2/label" />
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-2/hint" />
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert" />
                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/control-2/item">
                                    <xf:label ref="label" />
                                    <xf:value ref="value" />
                                    <xf:hint ref="hint" />
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </xf:select>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:output id="control-4-control" bind="control-4-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-4/label" />
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-4/hint" />
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert" />
                            </xf:output>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <fr:dropdown-select1 xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl" id="control-3-control" bind="control-3-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label" />
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint" />
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert" />
                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/control-2/item[label=('t1', 't2', 't4')]">
                                    <xf:label ref="label" />
                                    <xf:value ref="value" />
                                    <xf:hint ref="hint" />
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </fr:dropdown-select1>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

If im able to convert the checklist values into a comma separated list using XPath or some Orbeon Function, I'll have a solution:

```
<xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/control-2/item[label=(<list of values>)]">
  <xf:label ref="label" />
  <xf:value ref="value" />
  <xf:hint ref="hint" />
</xf:itemset>
```

where `<list of values>` looks like `'t1', 't2', 't3'`.

Comment: Are you using Form Builder? What is `<list of values>`? Why does that look like `'t1', 't2', 't3'`?

Comment: I am using formbuilder, `<list of values>` is what I want,` 't1', 't2', 't3'`, is an example of what the `<list of values>` should be. If I can convert the selected checklist values into a list like the above, then I can use XPath to populate the dropdown.

Comment: Your `<xf:select appearance="full">`, which is rendered as checkboxes, is bound to an element, and that element will be populated with a space-separated list of values corresponding to the items checked by the user. This is already happening out-of-the-box, and you don't need to do anything for that. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @avernet Are your refering to $control-2? The reference you would use to populate the calculate the value of a control (i.e., what im doing for  $control-4)? If thats what your suggesting, then that doesn't seem to work. I need a comma separated list to leverage the XPath's `item[label=('val1', 'val2',...,'valn')]` which only selects the matching items. Is there something analogous to the js one liner `array.filter( (val) => { return val.selected === true })` but for xpath/orbeon ?

Comment: Let's assume you're using an `<xf:select appearance="full">`, which stores a space-separated list of values in an element. I'll assume that list is in `/form/section-1/control-2`. Then you can build a comma-separated list from the space-separated list with the following XPath: `string-join(xxf:split(/form/section-1/control-2), ', ')`. Does this seem to lead in the right direction?

Comment: @avernet Yes thats excellent. Now is there anyway to refresh the `xf:itemset` within my `<fr:dropdown-select1>` after the form is initiated(Created)? I assume the control-2 data DNE within the forms when form elements are created ( I guess this is related to the forms lifecycle )

Comment: If the items your `xf:itemset` points to change, then the dropdown will automatically update. There is nothing you need to do for that to happen. And you'll let me know if I misunderstood your question.